# Visual Studio Cannot Find Database File

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, localdb

So I added a .mdf file to my solution just so I can have a basic database to read and write data to. However, every time I restart the program, the data I changed returns back to what it was prior to starting the program.

I read that this was due to it being copied to the source directory. However, when I do not copy it, Visual Studio is still looking in the same directory and it throws an error at run time. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Fiddling around with SQL Server database files is always messy - at best!

The **real solution** in my opinion (seeing that you've already installed SQL Server Express) would be to

1. install SQL Server Management Studio Express (if you haven't already done so)
2. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name
3. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: I would like the solution to work on any PC with SQL Server installed and I don't have rights to add a new database to the computers I'm using or even install software. I can use Visual Studio, run/write programs, but not much else.

Comment: @Taugenichts: if SQL Server is installed on any given computer, you *can* create a database **on the server** and use it there!

Comment: Right now I'm using a personal PC, but when I return to my campus on Monday I'll let you know if it works. +1 for the help until I can confirm. Thanks.

Comment: @Taugenichts: you can use the `sqlcmd` command line tool which should be installed on any computer with SQL Server - or you could even write a little C# utility yourself to create that database on any given computer ...